# trials from a multinomial distribution required to obtain 1 item in particular

Tags: probability, distributions

I have a set of outcomes $\{A, 2A, B, C\}$, which on a roll appear with probabilities $\{0.10, 0.15, 0.40, 0.35\}$ respectively.

How many rolls do I need to get 30 $A$ elements?

Comment: Is there a distinction between an "A" and a "2A"?  Does the latter count as an "A element"?  Regardless, all variants of your question have been asked and answered here: search for [coupon collector](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector) for the most general version.  Yours is a much simpler special case: look for information about the geometric distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the kind reply @whuber. Indeed the 'coupon collector' problem addresses the point I am interested in.